# Is it possible to call method from entity in Specification or QueryDSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, specifications

Is it possible to call method from Entity in Spring Data Specification or QueryDSL?

I have collection of shapes (few types with different parameters) and every shape has method countArea() in entity class. Is it possible to add parameter to search like "area" and use it as filter?
If not, is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Yes its possible to combine specifications with Querydsl, but we need more example code to properly adjust it to your use case.